# Tax: taking % off number

Tags: percentages

I've come across a problem that I'm unsure how to solve. I'm making a software program that needs to add/remove tax from a number. It gets a little tricky though, as the tax rate is changeable.

I need a formula that can remove a % off a number. But believe me, it's not as easy as it sounds.

Look below and see my problem; (Similar to how it looks in code)

```
taxRate = 15%
value = 200

// Add tax
value + (value / 100 * taxRate) = 230

value = 230

// Remove tax
value - (value / 100 * taxRate) = 195.5
```

When I remove the tax rate I get **195.5**. I need to get **200**.

Does anybody know how to solve this? Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

**Note** I would've asked the StackoverFlow community, but I thought a mathematician would be more helpful for this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a tax of $n\%$ to a base amount is the same as multiplying the base amount by
$$\frac{100 + n}{100}$$
To remove the tax, just multiply the after-tax amount by
$$\frac{100}{100+n}$$